Spring MongoRepository very slow to return entities
First disclaim: I've already seen these topics
==> Spring MongoRepository very slow to convert POJO
==> performance issue on Spring Data Mongodb
I clearly have a similar problem, but nothing in relation to @DBRef, and don't succeed (yet) to create my own converter to try something else.
In facts, I just join an old project (without any people with knowledge on it), and the first issue is performance. After multiple improvements, I still block on the last one : 60s to retrieve ~13.000 entities.
First, I thought it was because of the query itself ("find all where my_attribute IN (?)"). But if I run the query on MongoDB Compass, it took less than 1s. So the problem is cleary between Mongo and Spring.
The entity:
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyEntity{

    @Field(value = "classId")
    private String classId;

    @Field(value = "prodId")
    private String prodId;

    @Field(value = "attributes")
    private List<AttributeEntity> attributes;

    [...] // Constructors (with all args) / getters / setters / ...
}

The repository:
public interface MyEntityRepository extends MongoRepository<MyEntity, String> {

    List<MyEntity> findByProdIdIn(List<String> ids) throws SmartExchangeMongoException;
}

The request if I use Compass:
{ "prodId" : { "$in" : ["PROD_ID_1", "PROD_ID_ABCDE", "PROD_ID_0242525", ...] } }

There is an index on attribute "prodId".
We were on spring-data-mongodb 3.3.0, I tried on 4.4.0 without any difference.
It's really the method "findByProdIdIn" itself that took 60s to execute, I have a timer before and after the call.
So ... what next ?
Why it took so long for this query to execute ? Any advice on config', usage of repository, and so on ?
I come from SQL world, and clearly don't understand why it's so hard for Spring Data to transform mongo Document to Java entities.
If I do the same on MariaDB, Postgresql, or whatever, it never took so long to transforms entities. So, before trying something else, I would know if we are doing something wrong on a basic use case.
Anyway, I'm stuck =D
Thanks for reading.
================================
EDIT 1
After more tests, I realise that Compass use pagination, so it's "normal" that the request itself run in less than 0s. If it try to show more, it will be much slower (but Compass has limit of 100 max per pagination query, so I can't test for the whole result).
I've also made 2 more tests:

On MariaDB to simulate something similar: 500.000 MyEntity and 1.000.000 AttributeEntity. The same request, with ~13.000 random "prodId".
SpringData make the request and map it to java object in less than 2s...so ok, it's not 1.700.000 entities like I have on Mongo, but it's only 3x less, for 30x faster.

Made my own query, if we can't trust Spring:


@Query( "{'prodId' : { '$in' : ?0}}")
List<MyEntity> customFindByProdIdIn(List<String> ids) throws SmartExchangeMongoException;

The result is exactly the same...
